# displaying the items of advanced search without saving in folder outlook vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, advanced-search

I want to run an advance search in outlook through excel vba, in order to find some emails and create an automatic reply to one of them.

My problem is that I don't know how to deal with the results of the search as a group of Items, ordering them by date and replying to the most recent one WITHOUT saving them in any Search Folder.

So far, I was only able to run the advanced search and save the results of the search into a folder:

```
    Sub test()
        Dim Outl As Object
        Dim TESTEfolder As Object
        Dim Search As Object

        Set Outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set TESTEfolder = Outl.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("TESTE")
        Set Search = Outl.AdvancedSearch("'" & TESTEfolder.FolderPath & "'")
        Search.Save ("TESTEcopy") 'I want to skip this and handle the Items inside Search directly

    End Sub
```

Notes: I have to use LATE binding and the Advanced Search rather than Find/Restrict/InStr

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using VBA in Excel to do this?

Comment: Because this will be part of an Excel Workbook that will be distributed to several users so it should be self-contained

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to save the search. When advanced search is done the Outlook.Application object is raising an event:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/application-advancedsearch-method-outlook